# nar-maven-plugin change output path

Tags: maven

I am using nar-maven-plugin to build my c++ projects,everything is OK, the only problem is that the output is located at

```
..\target\nar\socketutility-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-amd64-Windows-gpp-shared\lib\amd64-Windows-gpp\shared
```

This is a long path, I have two questions for this:

1. can this path be represented by one variable like ${project.xx}?
2. can I customize this path?